# ASP.NET MVC 5 - @C# code not being translated at runtime

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-5

So I'm trying to dynamically pass some data to a javascript function to update some UI for the user.

```
 @Html.CheckBox("Sun1D", new { onclick = "addRemEvent(1, 'D', 
                   @((List<DateTime>)ViewBag.dates).ElementAt(0) , '#Sun1D');"
                  , htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

However at runtime, the code doesn't seem to get translated and I end up with

```
<input htmlAttributes="{ class = form-control }" 
 id="Sun1D" 
 name="Sun1D" 
 onclick="addRemEvent(1, &#39;D&#39;,
 @((List&lt;DateTime>)ViewBag.dates).ElementAt(0) , 
 &#39;#Sun1D&#39;);" 
 type="checkbox" value="true" />
```

Now you can see the problem here. There should be a date value in that javascript function call, but I'm just getting my C# code as a literal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're sending server-side code to the client as a string.  It's not going to execute that string, it's just going to send it to the client.

To simplify, instead of something like this:

```
new { onclick="some text @someCode more text" }
```

you'd want this:

```
new { onclick="some text " + someCode + " more text" }
```

In yours that might look something like:

```
new { onclick = "addRemEvent(1, 'D', " + ((List<DateTime>)ViewBag.dates).ElementAt(0) + " , '#Sun1D');" }
```

There's nothing special about the fact that it's Razor syntax, code is still code.  You're writing C# code to build a string to put in the `onclick` property of an object.  You'd build that string just like you build any other string in C#.  (Which means you could also make use of `string.Format()`, etc. if you like.)

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.CheckBox("Sun1D", new { onclick = "addRemEvent(1, 'D',"+ 
                   ((List<DateTime>)ViewBag.dates).ElementAt(0)+" , '#Sun1D');"
                  , htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

Comment: You should provide an explanation with your answer, not just a raw code dump.

Comment: @mason, some times, can be noticed some minor mistakes without explanation

Comment: @levent And sometimes so minor a mistake can be missed without an explanation. You should *always* include an explanation with your answer.